# Huawei 8 cant download from google play

Tags: google-play-store

So one of my apps gives the following message:

> your device isn't compatible with this version

to a `Huawei 8` user even though it is marked `supported` in the google play console.

All I have in mind is that the google play filter this app because of one of my permissions.

the permissions are: `android.permission.CAMERA`, `android.permission.FLASHLIGHT`.

the features are: `android.hardware.camera`, `android.hardware.faketouch`, `android.hardware.screen.portrait`.

So... **what can the problem be?**
In addition, **how can I check if the user can download the app?** (beside asking him to download every now and then)